# Ignoring filtered cells in array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array formula that sums the numbers in a “visits” column (not adding the value if the row has “district” in its “area” column, and using `LEFT` to strip off non-number characters present in some of the values in the “visit” column.

```
=IFERROR(SUM(IF(Area="District",0,IF(LEN(CareNumber)>0,IFERROR(VALUE(NumberofVisits),VALUE(LEFT(NumberofVisits,SEARCH(" ",NumberofVisits)))),0))),0)
```

Unfortunately, this does not ignore rows that are filtered out. I found the `SUBTOTAL` function that should be able to help, but it seems to throw a `#VALUE` error no matter how I’ve used it. Is there another way?

Some sample data:

[image: spreadsheet data]

My formula adds them up just fine, but doesn't ignore filtered rows.

Comment: Pls include sample data with expected results?

Answer (score 0):

[image]@Leighton F, use the below formula with CSE.

=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7<>"District")*(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(TRIM($B$2:$B$7),SEARCH(" ",TRIM($B$2:$B$7))-1)),$B$2:$B$7)))

Comment: The calculation is correct, but when I filter my data, the result still doesn't change. I appreciate the help though. :)